# React-Native Xcode build on TeamCity very slow > 20 mins

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, xcode6, teamcity-9.0

We have setup our React-Native project for CI with TeamCity. The builds were really fast taking about 3-4 mins. All of a sudden the build time increased to > 20 mins. Not able to figure out what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the build log where it slows down:

> [20:45:57]    /bin/sh -c
>   /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/ios/build/FTMOBX.build/KeyNoteDevices-iphoneos/FTMOBX.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
>   [20:46:25]+
>   DEST=/Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/ios/build/KeyNoteDevices-iphoneos/FTMOBX.app
>   [20:46:25]+ [[ KeyNoteDevices = \D\e\b\u\g ]] [20:46:25]+
>   BUNDLE_FILE=/Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/ios/build/KeyNoteDevices-iphoneos/FTMOBX.app/main.jsbundle
>   [20:46:25]+ node
>   /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js
>   bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false
>   --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/ios/build/KeyNoteDevices-iphoneos/FTMOBX.app/main.jsbundle
>   --assets-dest /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/ios/build/KeyNoteDevices-iphoneos/FTMOBX.app
>   [20:46:44]Scanning 943 folders for symlinks in
>   /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/node_modules
>   (8ms) [20:46:44]Scanning 943 folders for symlinks in
>   /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/node_modules
>   (9ms) [20:47:01]Loading dependency graph, done.
>   **[20:47:01]warning: the transform cache was reset. [21:05:56]bundle: start** [21:05:56]bundle: finish [21:05:56]bundle: Writing bundle
>   output to:
>   /Users/wsgtcadmin/Documents/buildAgent/work/5b087746a75a982e/ios/build/KeyNoteDevices-iphoneos/FTMOBX.app/main.jsbundle
>   [21:05:56]bundle: Done writing bundle output [21:05:56]bundle: Copying
>   403 asset files [21:05:56]bundle: Done copying assets [21:05:57]+ [[ !
>   -n false ]]

Comment: I am too working on the same stuff. But I got stuck with this error "React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h file not found
[16:56:50][CompileC] #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>". Have you faced this issue as well?